# org.hibernate.MappingException: collection foreign key mapping has wrong number of columns. Misleading Error details?

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Relation between a `World`, a `Map` and it's `Tile`s.

However I receive and error that I do not really understand:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: collection foreign key mapping has wrong number of columns: com.barbarus.state.world.Map.tiles type: component[worldId,x,y]
```

I don't really get what the issue with `Map.tiles` is there? and why it's describing it with `component[worldId,x,y]`? As you can see below the ID of a tile is `TilePosition` that should be defined like `[component[mapId,x,y]`. So the error messages kinda points out the `MutableSet<Tile>` but at the same time references the `MapPosition` class. I do not understand the associating between these two in the context of the error message.

Here is the definition of the entities:

```
@Entity
class World(
    @Id
    val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    val name: String = "default",
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "position.worldId")
    val maps: MutableSet<Map> = mutableSetOf()
) { //... }
```

```
@Entity
open class Map(
    @EmbeddedId
    val position: MapPosition,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "position.mapId")
    val tiles: MutableSet<Tile> = mutableSetOf()
) { //... }

@Embeddable
class MapPosition(
    var worldId: String,
    var x: Long,
    var y: Long
) : Serializable { //... }
```

```
@Entity
open class Tile(
    @EmbeddedId
    val position: TilePosition,
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH])
    val items: MutableSet<Item> = mutableSetOf()
) { //... }

@Embeddable
class TilePosition(
    var mapId: String,
    var x: Long,
    var y: Long
) : Serializable { //... }
```